# References issue in VS2013 while having 2 projects in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I'm experiencing some issues with references while using VS 2013 for a school project.

Basically, I have an ASP.NET Project (let's call it project1) that needs to call a little app from a Silverlight Project (project2). So my solution consists in the 2 projects, with project2 referenced in project1.

Both projects work perfectly fine while testing separately, but when together, this error shows up :

> CS0012: The type 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

My code line (which calls the project2) looks like that :

```
    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        @project2.function()
    </section>
```

### The facts are :

- I referenced System.Windows in project2
- I tried to reference System.Windows in project1, via Add > Reference, but it doesn't exist
- I tried to reference System.Windows in project1 manually, but it doesn't work either
- Tried different thing I found on the web but can't find any fix
- Apparently (as I understand) the call to project2 does not care about the System.Windows reference in project2 and is using the one in project1

If anyone as any idea, I'm pretty sure it's a dumb thing but I'm stuck since the morning on that one and can't go further...

Comment: There is not really enough info here to answer the question.  You can't actually reference a Silverlight project from a regular .Net project, as they target different runtimes.  Why exactly are you trying to call a method from the Silverlight project?

Comment: Yeah, I saw something talking about different runtime. So I managed to do something else, and forgot to put the question in 'resolved'.

Thank you anyway, I tried to do it like that because I misunderstood the subject of the project. But I actually understand now.